# Reversing a string in python based on block size in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im trying to reverse a string based on the block size given

for example

`"the price of food is 12 dollars"` and im given a block size of 4

i want the end result to be:

```
food of price the dollars 12 is
```

im not sure how to input this into python any help would be appreciated 
i need this to work for any block size

Comment: By block size do you mean the number of words that should be reversed at a time?

Comment: yes @lxop i do mean words at a time

Answer (score 6):

```
def chunks(seq, n):
    return [seq[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(seq), n)]

s = "the price of food is 12 dollars"
' '.join(' '.join(reversed(chunk)) for chunk in chunks(s.split(), 4))
```

Related: [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/312443/674039)

Comment: nice I was waiting for this kind of answer

Comment: i need this piece of code to pu into a function will this work? @wim

Comment: Yep, you just .. uh... put it into a function, good luck with that

Answer (score 5):

Using [`itertools` grouper recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
        "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
        # grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
        args = [iter(iterable)] * n
        return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

>>> text = "the price of food is 12 dollars"
>>> ' '.join(word for g in grouper(4, text.split()) 
                  for word in reversed(g) if word)
'food of price the dollars 12 is'
```

Comment: @root you can't, because then it uses another extra space. @wim's solution avoids this problem by have two `''.join`s, which I like better now. Try it for yourself to see

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially splitting the list, reversing it, then rotating it.

So this works:

```
>>> st='the price of food is 12 dollars'
>>> li=st.split()[::-1]
>>> n=3
>>> print ' '.join(l[n:]+l[:n])
food of price the dollars 12 is
```

Or, more directly:

```
>>> li='the price of food is 12 dollars'.split()[::-1]
>>> print ' '.join(li[3:]+li[:3])
food of price the dollars 12 is
```

Or, if you want it in a function:

```
def chunk(st,n):
    li=st.split()[::-1]  # split and reverse st
    return ' '.join(li[n:]+li[:n])

print chunk('the price of food is 12 dollars',3)
```

The key is:

```
st='the price of food is 12 dollars'  # the string
li=st.split()                         # split that
li=li[::-1]                           # reverse it
li=li[3:]+li[:3]                      # rotate it
' '.join(li)                          # produce the string from 'li'
```

Comment: +1 this is nice too awesome, what you doing first split into list reverse list then add back in chunks of block in string..Correct ??

Comment: Yes -- I added an explanation in the answer.

Comment: -1 this does not work for other cases.  for example, for input of 'a b c d e f' and chunk size of 2 we should get 'b a d c f e' but yours gives 'd c b a f e'